Why one of my variables in my ssf model doesn't give any result ? I just get NAs?
I'm currently creating an ssf model to analyse my data but I have an issue with one of the variables.
To put you in some context I have position data of a deer named Barbara. To explain its movement I chose several variables : slope, distance (distance of each step of the individual), delta_elevation and** var_NDVI**.
The last one is the one troubling me.

here is the output of the model : 

here is how i incorporated the raster data I told you about:


ssf_barbara <- ssf_barbara |> extract_covariates(landcover_corsica, where="both")
ssf_barbara <- ssf_barbara |> extract_covariates(elevation, where="both")


my NDVI data :

cervus_xyt <- st_sf('geometry' = cervus_clean$geometry, 
                    'timestamp' = cervus_clean$timestamp, 
                    'id'=cervus_ta$`individual-local-identifier`, 
                    'NDVI'= cervus_clean_env$`MODIS Land Vegetation Indices 250m 16d Terra NDVI`)

cervus_xyt<- cervus_xyt %>% filter(id=="Barbara")

cervus_xyt<-cbind(cervus_xyt, st_coordinates(cervus_xyt))

tibble <- tibble(x =cervus_xyt$X, y =cervus_xyt$Y, t = cervus_xyt$timestamp, id=cervus_xyt$id, NDVI=cervus_xyt$NDVI)
cervus_track <- amt::make_track(tibble, x, y, t, id, NDVI, crs = 4326)

cervus_track <- cervus_track |> mutate(sl_ = step_lengths(cervus_track))
summary(cervus_track$sl_)

amt::summarize_sampling_rate(cervus_track)

stps<- amt::track_resample(cervus_track, rate=hours(12),
                           tolerance=hours(1))
stps
stps <- filter_min_n_burst(stps, 3)
ssf_barbara <- steps_by_burst(stps, keep_cols = "both")

My NDVI data is actually extracted (not from a raster) but from a simple data frame from moovebank.
I don't think it's a class problem because I already checked that.
The only thing I can think about to explain the NA is that when I incorporated the NDVI data into my dataframe I didn't use a Raster like the other variables.

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. I suggest you visit this link for a simple guide to improve your post. Right now you need to add a sample of your data using  the output head() and dput() on your data so we can test your data together with your code that you used

What does ssf stand for?

sorry, it's step selection function

Try your best to include a small version of the data set that you can include in your post. Run your code using the small version and see if the issue still happens. If so, then you include that small dataset in the post and the shortest code needed to reproduce the results. As of now we can't really follow up anything with what you have provided.
